# Why asterisk in NSString disappeared while sending message?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Good day everyone, I'm new in Objective-C and a little bit confused.

When creating a NSString I should use an asterisk after NSString:

```
NSString *someString = @"string";
```

But when I need to send a message like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someString];
```

I should not. Why?

Comment: U have to send your string as [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@", someString];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all goes back to the fact that Objective-C is a layer on top of C, so your variables follow the same standards as they do in plain old C - among which, the distinction between variables holding actual objects and variables just pointing to an object, but not holding it.

In Objective-C practically all variables with an object type (for instance `NSString`, `NSArray`, etc.) are pointers so you could say that the distinction is a bit of a relic.

The upside is that you can mix plain C code into your Objective-C code without any problems, and there is a *lot* of useful C code out there, so all in all the fact that Objective-C still maintains its connections to C is a big advantage. It does make the learning process a little bit longer, though.

So to answer your question, when you declare a variable (or a parameter in a method or function) that should "contain" an object, you always have to declare it as a *pointer* to the object, since Objective-C as mentioned does not normally keep a complete object in its variables. Variables only point to objects that are stored elsewhere in memory. In C, a pointer is defined by putting an asterisk in front of its name, which is what you do in your example of the `NSString` variable.

Now, when you pass the variable in a message, you only pass the pointer to the actual object (and not the object itself), and hence you use the variable name without any asterisks.

In short, you use the asterisk in a variable declaration to tell the compiler that you are declaring a pointer variable, after which you don't have to use any asterisks in the rest of your code for that variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a string:

```
NSString *someString = @"string";
```

You create pointer to the memory where the string exists, you can think about pointer as address to the memory with that string.

And when you send a message you send the message to that memory so you don't use asterisk, compiler wouldn't allow you to use asterisk when you send message to that object.